# 2015 Brazilian Math Olympiad Number theory problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, functional-equations

> For $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>1}$ write $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_r^{a_r}$ with pairwise distinct prime numbers $p_i$. Now define the "fake derivative" of $n$ by $$f(n)=a_1\cdot p_1^{a_1-1}\cdot\ldots\cdot a_r\cdot p_r^{a_r-1}$$ Show that there are infinitely many numbers $n$ satisfying $$f(n)=f(n-1)+1$$

I've been facing this question for the last two weeks. Despite I didn't solve it, I noticed some properties of this "fake derivative" function. In the following, $\sigma$ will denote a permutation of $r$ letters, where $r$ stands for the number of distinct prime factors of $n$ and $p_i\neq p_j$ whenever $i\neq j$.

> - $f(p_1\cdot\ldots\cdot p_r)=1$
> - $f(n)=n$ if, and only if, $a_1\cdot\ldots\cdot a_r=p_1\cdot\ldots\cdot p_r$
> - In particular, if $n=p_1^{p_{\sigma(1)}}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_r^{p_{\sigma(r)}}$ then $f(n)=n$
> - No prime number is in the image of $f$
> - $f(n^k)=k^r\cdot n^{k-1}\cdot f(n)$ for all integers $k\geq 1$
> - $f(p_1^{a_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_r^{a_r})=f(p_1^{a_1})\cdot\ldots\cdot f(p_r^{a_r})$
> - In particular, if $\text{gcd}(m,n)=1$ then $f(n\cdot m)=f(n)\cdot f(m)$

I solved a kind of weaker version of the problem: there are infinitely many pairs $(n,m)$ such that $f(n)=f(m)+1$. Indeed, to prove this we only need to find one such pair, say, $(n_0,m_0)$ and then take $(n,m)=(p\cdot n_0, p\cdot m_0)$, where $p$ is any prime number that doesn't divide $n_0$ or $m_0$. Once there are finitely many primes that divide $n_0$ or $m_0$, there are infinitely many primes satisfying the preceding condition, and we are done. We can take, for example $(n_0,m_0)=(3^3,13^2)$. I found four other pairs: $(5^3,37^2)$, $(11^3,181^2)$, $(7^231^2,17^3)$ and $(19^3,541^2)$.

I also noticed that if $f(n)=n$ and $f(n-1)=n-1$, then the result obviously holds. But by the second property, we would have $n=p_1^{p_{\sigma(1)}}\ldots p_r^{p_{\sigma(r)}}$ and $n-1=q_1^{q_{\sigma(1)}}\ldots q_s^{q_{\sigma(s)}}$, where the $p_i$'s and $q_j$'s are pairwise distinct, since the primes that divide $n$ doesn't divide $n-1$. So if we find infinitely many numbers $n$ such that $n$ and $n-1$ are products of primes raised to a permutation of themselves, we are done.

Another thing that can (or cannot) be useful: the equation $f(n)=f(n-1)+1$ is equivalent to $f(n^2-n)=f(n)^2-f(n)$ (just use the fact that $\text{gcd}(n,n-1)=1$ and the last property).

You can read this problem (in Portuguese) [here](http://www.obm.org.br/export/sites/default/provas_gabaritos/docs/2015/3fase_nivel3_2015.pdf). It's problem 3.

Comment: For what it's worth, the function is tabulated at http://oeis.org/A203639 and some references are given there. Maybe your problem is discussed in one of the references.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you! I forgot to search there.

Comment: Have you seen the artofproblemsolving post on it? https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1154027p5469253

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete proof but i think this might work..

Starting from your weaker version:
We can find pairs $(n,m)$ such that $f(n)=f(m)+1$ and $\gcd(n,m)=1$. You have already given a couple of those above.
With one such pair we can find infinitely many other pairs $(n_i,m_i)=(p_i\cdot n, q_i\cdot m)$ where $p_i$ is any prime number satisfying: $p_i \nmid n$ and $q_i$ is any prime number  satisfying: $q_i \nmid m$ , also $p_i\neq q_i$.
We see that: $f(n_i)=f(m_i)+1$ and $\gcd(n_i,m_i)=1$ .
Now [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity) and the fact that $ \gcd(n_i,m_i)=1 $ tell us that we can find infinitely many pairs $ (x_j,y_j) $ such that $y_j\cdot m_i=x_j\cdot n_i -1 $ with: $ (x_j,y_j) = (x_0+k\cdot m_i,y_0+k\cdot n_i)$ for any integer $ k $.
It seems to me that we must always be able to find $ k $ for which $ (x_j,y_j) $ consists of only primes to the first power that are not in $(n_i,m_i)$.

Comment: You start from $f(a) = f(b)+1, gcd(a,b) = 1$ and you want two square-free integers $u,v$ such that $au=bv +1$, so that $f(au) = f(a) = f(b)+1 = f(bv)+1 = f(au-1)+1$, that's what you meant ? And see [this post ](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1154027p5925546)

Comment: @user1952009 Indeed that's what I meant.The article you  refer to already has a solution to the problem apparently. It also claims: 
'There exists infinitely many $n$ such that $an+x$ and $bn+y$ are squarefree.' although circumstances are not exactly the same. If that were to apply to the case above it would mean there are infinitely many Bezout's coefficients to satisfy $f(n_i)=f(n_i-1)+1$

Answer (score 0):

I would try to take $n$ of the form $27(169k +  144)$ so that$$n - 1 = 169(27k + 23).$$If one manages to pick $k$ such that $169k + 144$ and $27k + 23$ are both squarefree, and $169k + 144$ not divisible by $3$, and $27k + 23$ not divisible by $13$, then one has$$f(n) = f(27) = 27$$and$$f(n - 1) = f(169) = 26.$$To show that infinitely many $n$ fit the bill, one looks up the proof that a "random" number is squarefree with "probability" $6/\pi^2$, and I would modify the proof they give to compute the probability that a random number $k$ has the property$$\text{"}169k + 144\text{ is squarefree and not divisible by }3\text{"}$$and also the probability that a random number $k$ has the property$$\text{"}27k + 23\text{ is squarefree and not divisible by }13\text{".}$$There is little doubt that the sum of those two probabilities exceeds $1$, in which case you are done.

Try it out and let me know whether it works.

Comment: I see what you mean now. The percentage among all numbers of numbers $ k $ for which : '$169k+144$ is squarefree and not divisible by $3$' $ = A $ and percentage for which : '$27k+23$ is squarefree and not divisible by $13$' $ = B $. Now if $ A+B>100$% there must be overlap for infinitely many $k$. Very rough approximation ($ \frac{2}{3} \frac{6}{{\pi}^2}$ etc.) shows $ A = 40.5$% and $ B = 56.1$% which is not enough. Values larger than $ 3 $ and $ 13 $ will work, provided you can adapt the proof.